# Clojure, printing inside a loop

Tags: clojure

I made a simple function in Clojure to print some values.

```
(defn printboard [] (
    (dotimes [n 3]
      (println n)
      )
    )
  )

(printboard)
```

Now when i run this code as an application, it gives me an NullPointerException.
When i run the code in the REPL it works perfect. 
Why does my code give me an NullPointerExeption in the application but not in the REPL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are wrapping `dotimes` inside parentheses. Try the below code

```
(defn printboard []
    (dotimes [n 3]
      (println n)))

(printboard)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87JzyotSv3/XyMlNS1PoaAoM68kKT@xKEUhOpZLAQg0UvJLMnNTixWi8xSMIUJAQbC6nDyFPE1NTS4uDYQ2zf//AQ)